# IRootObjectProvider not available in Designer?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm a bit of a WPF newbie, so go easy on me please folks!

I am trying to implement a MarkupExtension, in which I want to reference the root element of the XAML which is calling the extension (I need its Name element to do a lookup).

The following code works fine at run time, but during design time I get an error in the designer window.

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnTypeAttribute(typeof(string))]
public class TranslateExtension : MarkupExtension
{

    public TranslateExtension(string key)
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var root = ((System.Xaml.IRootObjectProvider)serviceProvider).RootObject as FrameworkElement;
        return root.Name;
    }

}
```

gives me an error in designer of:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'InstanceBuilderServiceProvider' to
>   type
>   'System.Xaml.IRootObjectProvider'.

Which is sort of self explanatory - obviously ProvideValue is being called with a service provider which can't be converted to RootObjectProvider.

Is there any work around?  Or am I doing something really silly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IRootObjectProvider is not available in WPF 4 as of now, it will be included in future. You can programmatically use Xaml Services that supports IRootObjectProvider but WPF does not support it yet.

Comment: How do you know it is not supported in WPF 4?

Comment: Its written in MSDN clearly that it is not supported. It is only supported in System.Xaml.XamlServices, but not in WPF, the expected namespaces are different.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you supposed to do something like

```
var service = (IRootObjectProvider)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider));
```

It still does not help with designer however...

Comment: While this does not work with IRootObjectProvider, it does work with IProvideValueTarget. This helped me a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rootObjectProvider = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider)) as IRootObjectProvider;
```